# How to Transfer OCI Sticker from expired US passport to new US passport

Tags: india, us-citizens

My elderly relative is a naturalized US Citizen (since 1970) from India.

In 2012 he got OCI (Overseas Citizen of India)

1. Booklet
2. Sticker attached to his US Passport

This relative recently renewed his expired US Passport. To avoid any hassle traveling to India he wishes to transfer the OCI sticker from his Expired US Passport to his New US Passport.

When I called OCI office, they said the Government of India no longer issues the Sticker, hence he will be ok.

When I told my elderly relative this he said he believes them 1%. He was born and raised in India, he knows what is said and written is different from reality, hence I am posting question on this forum.

How to transfer OCI sticker from expired US passport to new US passport.

NOTE: Several relatives who tried taking their expired US passport with OCI sticker along with new US passport without sticker had difficulty entering India, even though they have OCI lifetime membership (again, India is entirely different system, hence I am posting here)

Comment: The OCI sticker is not required nor issued anymore, just the OCI card (booklet). Has your relative got the OCI card? That is all you need to travel.

Comment: Yes @MichaelHampton he has that booklet (I guess they call it card, it resembles a passport)

Comment: Oh yes, now I see that you wrote "booklet" in your question.

Answer (score 4):

To make this an actual answer:

It is no longer necessary to have any OCI sticker, and immigration officials will not require it. Instead, you can present your OCI card (booklet) in its place, in addition to your passport for your other nationality.

The [official web site](https://boi.gov.in/content/overseas-citizen-india-oci-cardholder) does say this, but in much less clear language. You may also read a [contemporary news report](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/oci-cards-enough-to-visit-india/article8371422.ece) which explains the new procedure: It is necessary only to present your passport and OCI card when checking in for your flight and when arriving in India.